# Audio with very much noise except for OMXPlayer

Tags: audio, omxplayer

I'm developing an arcade cabinet with my Raspberry Pi, but I'm running into some problems regarding sound. When I try to play an MP3 file with omxplayer (`omxplayer -o local music.mp3`), it sounds very good. However, when I try to do it with any other program or library (mpg321 or libmpg123) I get a lot of static and very faintly in the background I can hear the music or sound playing. Is there any way to play sounds properly without OMXPlayer as I haven't been able to find a C API for it.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi B+ and the analog audio output.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While I am not sure whether it might matter, could you please specify which Pi you're using and which audio output is used (I guess the analogue one)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it to my post

Comment: No answer will be good enough. The rpi sound is intended for basic activity. External sound card is highly advised. White noise created by power noise and cpu interference.

Comment: Could you perhaps recommend an external sound card for usage with the raspberry pi?

Comment: There are many USB Sound options, often less than us$ 5.  There are a few caveats to run them but but sound is much better. You can add a few capacitors on your RPI to reduce the noise, but the solution is not 'portable'.

Comment: Sound like you've got your ALSA config messed up. 
What does `aplay -l && arecord -l` and `cat /proc/asound/modules` say?

Comment: I figured it out eventually, it seemed that I had to increase the volume using amixer (`amixer set PCM -- 100%`), somehow omxplayer bypassed this